# images having arabic names with encoding not opening

Tags: android, image, encoding, url-encoding

I am making an Android app where I have image url that contain arabic characters.

Below is the code I am using...

```
Log.e(TAG, "Video Image -- > " + Uri.encode(data.get(position).getPhoto().toString()));
Picasso.with(act).load(Uri.encode(data.get(position).getPhoto().toString()))
        .resize(pW, pH)
        .centerCrop()
        .skipMemoryCache()
        .error(R.drawable.img_table_view)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.img_table_view)
        .into(viewHolder.image);
```

The sample URL for  as below.

```
http://www.ssss.com/Karikatir/سبسي3ILAWESVVSKNVMWYLLTFWRASZ.jpg
```

The output of Log is as below.

```
10-19 10:00:08.038  25617-25617/com.sss.app E/VideosAdapter﹕ Video Image -- > http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ssss.com%2FKarikatir%2F3ILAWESVVSKNVMWYLLTFWRASZ.jpg
```

***Any idea why image is not displaying even after encoding url?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally below is what I did...

### *Step 1 : Extract image name from URL*

```
String imageName = "http://www.sss.com/test.png";
imageName = imageName.replaceAll("http://www.sss.com/", "");
```

### *Step 2 : Encode this image name instead of full URL*

```
String encodedURL = "http://www.sss.com/" + Uri.encode(imageName);

Picasso.with(act).load(encodedURL)
        .resize(pW, pH)
        .centerCrop()
        .skipMemoryCache()
        .error(R.drawable.img_table_view)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.img_table_view)
        .into(viewHolder.image);
```

So encoded url will be as below.

```
String encodedURL = "http://www.sss.com/" + Uri.encode(imageName);
```

***Note :*** *If there are spaces in URL you will need to update code as below.*

```
String encodedURL = "http://www.sss.com/" + Uri.encode(imageName).replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

***Don't replace space with %20 before encoding as it will encode %20 which will go to incorrect url. So replacing spaces with %20 will be after encoding.***

*Posting the answer so it will help someone as I don't find solution online...*